# Form validation message not showing while using partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm working on a ASP.NET core 2.0 application where I created a form to enter data. While checking if the validation works I noticed that there are no validation messages being displayed for a required property of my view model.

When the required input is empty and I press save I can't continue, so the input is required but there is no message to be seen.

The view model for my form view has a list of view models as a property because part of the form has to be changed dynamically.

This is my main view model:

```
public class SettingsViewModel
{
    public List<KeyValueViewModel> KeyValuePairs { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the KeyValueViewModel

```
public class KeyValueViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Key")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Key is required")]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Value")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Value is required")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Guid SettingFileId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Guid, string> SettingFileDropdownOptions { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the main view:

```
@model SettingsViewModel
<form asp-action="Create" id="SettingsForm">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label asp-for="@Model.KeyValuePairs[0].Key" class="control-label col-md-3 no-left-padding"></label>
            <label asp-for="@Model.KeyValuePairs[0].Value" class="control-label col-md-offset-1 no-left-padding"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.KeyValuePairs.Count; i++)
    {
        var keyValuePair = Model.KeyValuePairs[i];
        keyValuePair.Id = i;
        <div id="KeyValuePairsContainer">
            @Html.Partial("_settingKeyValue", keyValuePair)
        </div>
    }
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 no-left-padding">
        <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
        <textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control" ></textarea>
        <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 no-left-padding">
        <input type="submit" value="Opslaan" class="btn btn-primary" id="Submit" />
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="btn btn-default" id="Cancel">Annuleren</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here the partial view that gets rendered:

```
@model KeyValueViewModel
<div class="form-group col-md-4 no-left-padding">
    <input asp-for="@Model.Key" class="form-control  col-md-3" id="KeyValuePair_Key_@Model.Id" name="KeyValuePairs[@Model.Id].Key" required="required"/>
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Key" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4 no-left-padding">
    <input asp-for="@Model.Value" class="form-control col-md-3" id="KeyValuePair_Value_@Model.Id" name="KeyValuePairs[@Model.Id].Value" required="required" />
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Value" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

The validation message on the Key and Value properties do not get displayed when they should. We tested the Description property of the SettingsViewModel by adding a required tag with a message, and this worked just fine.

How do I get the validation message of the KeyValueViewModel displayed in my main view?

**Edit**

```
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Key" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Doesn't get updated to class="field-validation-error" when it should be

Comment: did you try including `jquery.validate.js` inside the partial view itself?

Comment: In my main view I have the standard @section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
} 
code which includes the jquery.valide.js library

Comment: Adding the same code to the partial view doesn't work (I think because it just adds the same library twice)

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, `asp-validation-for` does not work, if the input has a `name="..."` attribute. Removing the `name` attribute from the input may solve the problem.

This is because asp.net validation itself uses the name attribute and it expects it to match the name of the attribute in `asp-for` (exactly, including the first capital letter).

Answer (score 0):

`asp-validation-for` accepts property name

instead of

```
<span asp-validation-for="@Model.Value" class="text-danger"></span>
```

should be

```
<span asp-validation-for="Value" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Comment: Just tried this, doesn't solve the problem unfortunately

Comment: @Jeroen did you modify `<input asp-for="@Model.Value"..` to `<input asp-for="Value"` also ?

Comment: Yes I did. Same for Key

Comment: Try to remove `id="..."` from `input` elements

Comment: I use Id's for my acceptation tests and for my javascript code and I don't see how removing the Id will solve the problem.

Comment: `asp-validation-for` tag helper links validation message to `input` element with it's `id`. otherwise, how it can't know which input to validate.

Comment: Okey when I remove the Id from the input it gets a id of "Key" and when i click submit without filling in the key it updates the class of input to input-validation-error but this doesn't change the span element's class

Comment: This also doesn't add a new span inside my field-validation span